# intertext() takes exactly 1 positional arguement (2 given)

Tags: python, xml

Not exactly sure how to deal with this error...

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('network_objects.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for network in root.iterfind('network_object'):
    name = network.find('Name')
    class_name = network.find('Class_Name')
    color = network.find('color')
    for netmaskElement in network.iterfind('netmask'):
        netmask = network.itertext('netmask')    
    for ipaddyElement in network.iterfind('ipaddr'):
        ipaddy = network.find('ipaddr')
    print (name.text,class_name.text,ipaddy.text,netmask,color.text)
```

Error:

```
builtins.TypeError: itertext() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
line 10, in <module>
netmask = network.itertext('netmask')
```

The XML itself, as an example:

```
<network_objects>
<network_object>
<Name>Internal-192.168.112.0_24b</Name>
<Class_Name>network</Class_Name>
<add_adtr_rule>false</add_adtr_rule>
<broadcast><![CDATA[allow]]></broadcast>
<color><![CDATA[dark orchid]]></color>
<comments><![CDATA[no comment]]></comments>
<edges/>
<ipaddr><![CDATA[192.168.112.0]]></ipaddr>
<location><![CDATA[internal]]></location>
<location_desc><![CDATA[]]></location_desc>
<netmask><![CDATA[255.255.255.0]]></netmask>
<type><![CDATA[network]]></type>
</network_object>
</network_objects>
```

There are course other objects that do *not* contain netmask, which I assume is where the error is coming from, however I assumed the for loop would correct for that.

How do I fix this? :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the `itertext( 'netmask')` to `itertext()`

The documentation shows that it does not receive an additional parameter, as you are currently doing.

[itertext documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext)

Comment: If I do that, I get 'builtins.NameError: name 'netmask' is not defined'

Comment: @Numpty then you did something else instead.

Comment: Care to be more specific? If I go to print 'netmask', it is undefined. This may be part of the "fix", but it's not working

Comment: You define `netmask` inside of the for loop itself. Make sure that this for loop is actually entered. `for netmaskElement in network.iterfind('netmask'):` If the for loop is not entered then `netmask` is never defined.

Comment: @Numpty you seem to confuse `netmask` and `'netmask'`, for example.

Comment: @Sean - if I do a simple print statement within that loop, I see it get printed constantly. What's the real problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use .find like you have in the rest of the loop?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('network_objects.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for network in root.iterfind('network_object'):
    name = network.find('Name')
    class_name = network.find('Class_Name')
    color = network.find('color')
    for netmaskElement in network.iterfind('netmask'):
        netmask = network.find('netmask')    
    for ipaddyElement in network.iterfind('ipaddr'):
        ipaddy = network.find('ipaddr')
    print (name.text,class_name.text,ipaddy.text,netmask,color.text)
```

Comment: I had that earlier was well (was trying a bunch of different ways of doing this). netmask still ends up being 'not defined'